# PAdES electronic signature in java

Tags: java, electronic-signature, pades

Well as the title says, I was asked to perform an application with electronic signature PAdES. Sign PDF documents with this, but they know how to interpret these signatures in java, if someone have worked with something like this to tell me how I can validate PAdES.

Thanks, Greetings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A first aproach could be read the **ETSI TS 102 778-1** document. 
http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/102700_102799/10277801/01.01.01_60/ts_10277801v010101p.pdf

Here it's described a general overview of the PAdES signature types.

Depending on what form you want to implement you should validate the signatures according to different restrictions and checks.

The java library you are looking for is **iText** > http://itextpdf.com/

Comment: PDFBox is an open source alternative too: https://pdfbox.apache.org